# How to select the search input control on html when you click a hyperlink?

Tags: html, anchor

I am looking for a simple solution to select a search input box when you press a hyperlink.

I would be nice if this could be implemented without JavaScript, only by using relative anchors.

In my case it looks that the input already has an `id` but there is no anchor defined for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `label` with the `for` is what you are looking for. Anchor tags don't interact with input fields, unless you define it with JavaScript.